Jest testcase failing with "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the <Module> (?)" because of Non class provider tokens in NestJS
I am trying to run the following test case with npm run test src/categories/categories.service.spec.ts and I'm getting the following Error.
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the POSTGRES_PROVIDER_CategoriesRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument POSTGRES_PROVIDERDataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - Is TypeOrmModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If POSTGRES_PROVIDERDataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
    - If POSTGRES_PROVIDERDataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing POSTGRES_PROVIDERDataSource */ ]
      })

categories.service.spec.ts looks like below
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CategoriesModule } from './categories.module';

describe('CategoriesService', () => {
  let testModule: TestingModule;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    testModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports:[CategoriesModule]
    }).compile();
  });

  it('should validate the app module', () => {
    expect(testModule).toBeDefined();
  });
});

CategoriesModule is as below. This repo is using tokens for both Database actions and services and repositories
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { CategoriesService } from "./categories.service";
import { CategoriesRepository } from "./categories.repository";
import { DATABASE_TOKENS, SERVICE_TOKENS } from "../../src/constants";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Categories } from "./models/Categories";

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Categories], DATABASE_TOKENS.POSTGRES_PROVIDER)],
    providers: [{
        provide: SERVICE_TOKENS.CATEGORIES_SERVICE,
        useClass: CategoriesService
    },
    {
        provide: SERVICE_TOKENS.CATEGORIES_REPOSITORY,
        useClass: CategoriesRepository
    },
    ],
    exports: [SERVICE_TOKENS.CATEGORIES_SERVICE, SERVICE_TOKENS.CATEGORIES_REPOSITORY]
})
export class CategoriesModule { }


My app.module.ts has the following in the imports as below
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            name: DATABASE_TOKENS.POSTGRES_PROVIDER,
            useClass: TypeOrmConfigServicePostGres,
        }),
        CategoriesModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})

Additionally My categories.service.ts and categories.repository.ts looks like this
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Categories } from "./models/Categories";
import { ICategoryService } from "./categories.interface";
import { FetchCategoriesDTO } from "./categories.dto";
import { SERVICE_TOKENS } from "../../src/constants";
import { ICategoryRepository } from "./categories.interface";

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService implements ICategoryService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(SERVICE_TOKENS.CATEGORIES_REPOSITORY)
        private readonly _categoryRepository: ICategoryRepository,
    ) {}

    /**
     * Fetches categories based on the provided DTO.
     * @param dto - Data Transfer Object containing filter parameters.
     * @returns A promise resolving to an array of Categories.
     */
    async fetchCategories(dto: FetchCategoriesDTO): Promise<Categories[]> {
        const { onlyActive } = dto;
        return this._categoryRepository.fetchCategories(onlyActive);
    }
}

import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ICategoryRepository } from "./categories.interface";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { DATABASE_TOKENS } from "../../src/constants";
import { Categories } from "./models/Categories";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesRepository implements ICategoryRepository {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Categories, DATABASE_TOKENS.POSTGRES_PROVIDER)
        private readonly _categories: Repository<Categories>,
    ) {}

    async fetchCategories(onlyActive: boolean): Promise<Categories[]> {
        const queryObject = onlyActive ? { isActive: true } : {};
        console.log(queryObject);
        return this._categories.find({
            where: queryObject,
        });
    }
}


I am using "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.1", and @types/jest": "29.2.4 and "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0"
I need help on why the concatenation is happening before dependency check and how to make this test case run? Thanks for going through the entire code

I think you don't need to import your CategoriesModule in your TestingModule.
Instead, just bring your CategoriesService as a provider (this is the service you which to test). You also have to add all the injected services that are present in the constructor of the service you which to test.
const mockCategoryRepository = {
  fetchCategories: jest.fn(),
  ... // you can add here the rest of the functions implemented in your repository, if needed
}


describe('CategoriesService', () => {
  let service: CategoriesService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        CategoriesService,
        {
          provide: SERVICE_TOKENS.CATEGORIES_REPOSITORY,
          useValue: mockCategoryRepository,
        },
        // For now, that should be all you need, but if `CategoriesService` happens to have other injected services, you will have to add them here
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<CategoriesService>(CategoriesService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('fetchCategories', async () => {
    const inputDto = { onlyActive: true, foo: 'bar' };
    jest.spyOn(mockCategoryRepository.fetchCategories).mockResolvedValueOnce([])

    const result = await service.fetchCategories(inputDto);

    expect(result).toEqual([]);
    expect(mockCategoryRepository.fetchCategories).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)
  })
});

This should work with this simple test case. Don't forget to add other test cases (especially error cases)
